# WordJS/OfficeJS how to get unique id for a paragraph

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

How to get get unique id for a paragraph in WordJS. There are 2 not-documented fields. _Id is always 0 and _ReferenceId is changed each time when I get paragraph. Or is there a way to store my custom property for paragraph?

```
 _Id: number;
 _ReferenceId: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

getting the paragraph ID is something we are thinking about adding to the Word JS API, and its very useful in some specific scenarios but is something not supported as of today, so, for now, your best bet i agree is to use the content control. You can set the appearance of the content control to "none" so that its invisible to the end user.

Comment: Did this ever get implemented? I'm working on an add-in which needs paragraph IDs in order to work.

Comment: Is there any update as of today for how can we get unique paragraph ID?

Comment: @edcs, did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: @RishabhSagar - I ended up wrapping the paragraphs in a content control and using the ID from it.

Comment: @edcs Thanks for the reply edcs, achieved this using tracked objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact these non-document fields, but both are temporary, and neither should be used.

The best way to capture a particular paragraph is via a content control or a binding object (which effectively creates a content control for you).

Comment: I can't use content control. Can I "set/write" some property for Paragraph that will not reset each time I load Paragraph? Or can I add some hidden element for each paragraph?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what prevents you from using the content control / binding?  Is it the fact that it becomes visible?  If that's the case, perhaps can you hide it?  And get the surrounding paragraph from the hidden content control?..

Comment: yes, because it's visible and because I need to work with ooxml data and most of all because content control brings too much changes to ooxml. @michael-zlatkovsky and I am a little curious, why word don't have any UID concept for a paragraph?

Comment: What would a unique ID for a paragraph mean, if you can insert a newline in the middle of the paragraph (which one does the UID belong to now), or merge two paragraphs (which UID gets lost?)

Comment: A content control (or an Office.js Binding) allows the user/developer & the platform to mutually agree on what the bounds of a particular range/paragraph/etc. is.  This is very much like a "Named Range" (or, again, an Office.js binding) in Excel.

What is preventing you from working with OOXML data within the content control?